# javascript package manager that doesn't require node.js

Tags: javascript, package-managers

I'm looking for a JavaScript package manager that doesn't require node.js to be installed and preferably just works with standard command line tools. Is something like this available?

Comment: Most JavaScript stuff outside of the browser uses Node nowadays. Is there any particular reason you're avoiding it?

Comment: NPM is made for Node packages. You wouldn't need it if you weren't using Node (remembering that you sometimes just want the command-line tools, you still need Node installed).. You could use gems, but you'd have to install Ruby. What is it you want to use this package manager for? Also, for what OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [CommonJS Package Manager](https://github.com/kriszyp/cpm)?

> CPM (CommonJS Package Manager) is designed for simple, straightforward
>   installation of CommonJS packages into a target location/package. This
>   is specifically designed to make it easy to install packages for use
>   in the browser or any server side JS environment (like Node). CPM is
>   based on the CommonJS Mappings specification, and will install all
>   dependencies listed in the dependencies or mappings hash.

By default it uses Rhino (*since the JVM is installed almost everywhere*, quoting their comment).